# Real world user activity logging strategy for web applications

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a web application and my client requests that he wants to know.

I have come up with two ideas.
I would like to have my ideas verified if they are correct.

These are the client requirements.
who: who the visitor is(e.g. remoteAddress-IP)
when: what time the visitor did something on the web application
what: what exact action did the visitor take, such as "pushed print button"
where: which page, e.g. a URL the visitor accessed

My idea 1.
Simply issue an SQL query to log user activities for everyone visiting the web site.
If the visitor clicked on a link to a page, the web application would write the user activity to the database and render the requested page.
I think this will have a bad impact on user experience. Page rendering could get slower because it has to do extra work. Will this method end up issuing too many SQL queries and ultimately be a bad idea ?

My idea 2.
Start a new thread for each user or each user activity such as clicking print button.
Page rendering go on at its own speed and logging will be seperately done in the thread.
 I think this might create too many threads. Is this a good idea or would it end up using too much resources ?

I wonder if any of those are a good, real world practice. If there is a better way, please share. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation 1: Profile your application with and without your database logging system. You may find that DB logging meets your performance needs without major architectural changes or performance tuning.

If you find that you're able to sustain your throughput requirements, but occasionally back up during peak periods, you could move the DB logging into a single thread and pass log messages using a concurrent queue from `java.util.concurrent`. That will be much more efficient than forking a separate thread for each log event.

My suspicion is that if you find a performance issue, you'll find the bottleneck to be the database. But that's just a hunch - you'll have to profile your own setup to find the strengths and weaknesses.

Note: To compare performance with and without logging enabled, you could configure an on/off boolean or specific log levels at startup into final static variables. The JIT will optimize out any code contained in an `if (loggingEnabled)` or `if (logLevel > 3)` block, if those conditions are guaranteed to be false. That lets you run the same code with and without logging, without paying a performance penalty for the logging code when profiling the current (non-logging) approach.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons it's better to separate the log processing from page rendering, this can be best done using JMS.

When the user does some action all what you need to do is that you create the log object and send a JMS message using message source (JMS Queue should be suitable).

at the other end (message sink), you need to setup a message sink that receives messages and log them (to DB in your case).

this decoupling ensures minimum impact on user activities and reliable logging for use actions.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1 is good. Create a utility method to log the entries into the database. So every time you want to log some event, just call this method. Shouldn't take too much of your server resources, nor will it slow down the response time considerably.

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem seems to fit the **Producer / Consumer** pattern.

You have many threads processing user requests that will *produce* a request to write information into a database. You will have one single (or maybe more than one) thread *consuming* those requests and write the data to the database.

There are many ways to implement this in Java. You could:

- start a new thread each time you want to log a piece of information into the database
- use a shared `ExecutorService` with a limited number of threads, that will get reused and avoid many kinds of overhead
- use a shared `BlockingQueue` in which you will put log requests from your servlets, and have one (or more) thread `take()` elements from it in a loop and write data to the database according to the element you took

In any case, I would encapsulate this logic in a `RequestLogger` class, for instance:

```
public class RequestLogger {
  private final Thread thread;
  private final BlockingQueue<LogRequest> logRequestQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  public RequestLogger() {
    this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        try {
          while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            final LogRequest req = logRequestQueue.take();
            // ... log it to the database somehow ...
          }
        } catch (Exception e) { ... do something ... }
      }
    });
  }

  public void start() { thread.start(); }
  public void stop() { thread.interrupt(); }
  public void log(...) {
    logRequestQueue.offer(new LogRequest(...));
  }
}
```

You instantiate this class one time, call `.start()`, and you are ready to log everything you want.

If you want (for example, because you see that there are log requests accumulating too fast), you could change the logic in the `while(...)` loop to take more requests at a time (if available), and make your code issue a single write to the database, or write in a single transaction, or something like this.

It really depends on your particular scenario, but if you have a performance issue, the bottleneck is going to be the database.

Answer (score 0):

Modern logging framework supports the idea of ASYNCHRONOUS loggin. Fro example there is an [log appender in LogBack](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) which support Async logging with a very good response time.